# Nginx with private domain name returns 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, centos7

I am noobie with nginx and new to manuall server setup ...

I have simple nginx server, when accessing with `ip:port` its ok, I am trying to setup domain name for my host.

```
server {
        listen       80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name  farhadadeli2.ir www.farhadadeli2.ir;

        root   /xxx;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {            
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }             

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www56.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }


    }
```

`farhadadeli2.ir` is not a registered domain so I have set `185.208.172.243 farhadadeli2.ir` in my local system's windows host file.

If I open `http://farhadadeli2.ir/index.html` in my browser I am getting `503 Service Unavailable` .... weird thing is that if I access this domain using a proxy server it work's just fine and loads the index page!!!

I restarted dns service in my centos7 server and flushed dns in my local windows system (`ipconfig /flushdns`) but I am still getting the `503 Service Unavailable` message !!!

What can I do to fix this??

Do I need to setup some dns server in my centos server ?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem on my system, the config works. Meaning this is something on you local system, which is out of scope of this site.

Try farhadadeli2.ir/index.html does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old but a few notes regarding setting up Centos 7 for HTTP.

**Firewall**

Centos 7 uses '[firewalld](https://firewalld.org/documentation/)' rather than iptables. The firewall can be configured via 'firewall-cmd' which must be run as an elevated user (sudo).

By default all services, with the exception of ssh, are blocked therefore http must be explicitly allowed. A common mistake when adding a service is not setting the changes as permanent.

Open http permanently using the following command;

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=http --add-service=https --zone=public --permanent
```

or

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=80/tcp --add-port=443/tcp --zone=public --permanent
```

After executing the above both http & https will be opened for the Public zone and saved as permanent.

For experimental purposes you can add & remove ports & services without the --permanent option and if something goes wrong you can recover using firewall-cmd --reload.

**Apache / Nginx**

Install Apache or Nginx, the choice is yours. You can use any http server you like.

```
sudo yum install apache
```

or

```
sudo yum install nginx
```

In my experience, out of the box both Apache & Nginx are ready to serve pages and can be loaded for testing. Configure your chosen server to start after each reboot.

```
# For apache    
sudo systemctl enable httpd.service
sudo systemctl start httpd.service

# For Nginx
sudo systemctl enable nginx.service
sudo systemctl start nginx.service
```

**Verify it is working locally**

You should be able to load your blank website by installing the links tool.

```
sudo yum -y install links
links http://localhost
```

Your web site should be visible and being served from *localhost* and you should now do the same for your non-localhost IP, for example; 'links http://192.168.0.10' and verify the same result.

**Domain Name**

If you are creating a development environment for yourself and the server is on the same network as you then you don't need a domain name. You should be able to load your server via your browser using the URL http://192.168.0.10 (obviously replace with the server IP). If you are having only a single website on the server you can also access it from the internet after forwarding port 80 on your router. Outside access URL would be http://your_public_ip_address (google 'whats my ip').

However, if you are going to have multiple websites you should get a domain name otherwise the server cannot distinguish between them. There are many free domain name providers such as 'noip.com' and 'dyn.com'. You can point various domain names at your public ip and successfully run a development environment.

The above is the basics for setting up a home web server. The things to remember are;

1. Firewall port must be opened,
2. Http server install and tested
3. No your public IP address
4. Appropriate ports forwarded

Once you have done all that and tested the website works you should reboot and re-test and ensure all services start as they should.

**You are done**

I hope this helps someone.